# Open a new tab using JavascriptExecutor of selenium in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am using

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open();");
```

to open a new tab. It works fine in Chrome using selenium driver but not in IE, any suggestions? Thanks

Have tried this also: but no luck

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');");
```

Comment: Is the problem that a new top-level browsing context isn’t opened at all, or that the new page is opened in a new window instead of a new tab?

Comment: This is because of browser settings. See https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/force-ie-to-open-link-in-new-tab/ (*Open links from other programs in*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering if anyone gets the same issues

Step 1:

> Internet Options > General Tab > Click on Settings > Click on Tabs >
>   Select When Pop-up is encountered to Always open pop-ups in a new tab

Step 2:

> Now go to Privacy and Add website to allow popups from

Comment: There is no guarantee that manually opening a new window with JavaScript in the IE driver will work. In particular, you may be able to get a new top-level browsing context (tab or window) to open, but there is no guarantee that the IE driver will be able to control the resulting new tab or window. Whenever anyone asks, "How do I open a new [tab|window] using WebDriver," it's always useful to drill down on why they think such an operation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

the following may work for you:

```
String theURL = "type the url in here"; 
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0]),theURL");
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException, it would not going to work it throwing an javascript exception.